# How to change where mac terminal looks for a specific program?

Tags: ios, macos, terminal

I installed chromedriver to `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver` using homebrew and see

```
Linking Binary 'chromedriver' to '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'.
chromedriver was successfully installed!
```

But when I try `chromedriver --version` I see

```
-bash: /Users/s/.rbenv/shims/chromedriver: No such file or directory
```

When I opened a new terminal and try the same thing, I see

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /Users/s/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/chromedriver:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /Users/s/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
/Users/s/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem chromedriver-helper (>= 0.a) with executable chromedriver (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

I would like to completely ignore/override previously installed version(s) of chromedriver and simply have chromedriver installed and operate the 'usual' way (as though it had never previously existed on my machine). Since the brew install seemed to have been successful, I presume I simply need to tell mac terminal where to go to look for the newly installed chromedriver. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can either call it directly from its real, full path `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`, or update your `PATH` environment variables so that `/usr/local/bin` has priority over `~/.rbenv/shims`

Comment: With the latter option, is it as simple as editing the PATH environment variable so `/usr/local/bin` comes before `~/.rbenv/shims`? Also you say environment variable**s** - is that just a typo?

Comment: Yes, flip them over. And yes, you can have several lines regarding PATH, like `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`